# some part of URL path is removed and double nagivation in browser history

Tags: angular

I am using the `navigate` function of `Router` in angular. This is resulting in navigating once but creating two navigations in history and URL is automatically updated with some part of URL being stripped off like mentioned below:

`this.router.navigate(['buses','big','bus-details'],queryParamas:{busId:'abc'});` then in the first navigation the url would be `localhost:4200/buses/big/bus-details?busId=abc` but not even in a second the url will be updated to `localhost:4200/buses/big/bus-details` and when I click back button of browser I am taken to url `localhost:4200/buses/big/bus-details?busId=abc` although the `ngOnInit()` function is called only once while moving from first update to second update of url.

I have always been navigating like this but there has never been a problem. I have even checked that `NavigationStart` event is only fired once.

What I am looking for is that this update of URL should not happen, what can I do to prevent update of  URL while navigating?

Update: I have observed this error occurs only when routing through a specific feature module but If I route to the module from Root `AppModule` this URL updation doesn't take place and neither are two navigations created i.e. I don't need to click back button twice to go the path/component from which I called navigate function. So this seems to be an error in feature module through which the navigations are being done and not the components to which I am navigating.

Comment: Please include your navigate function, that may help us to understand where you might have gone wrong

Comment: This navigation function is received from `Router` object that we get from constructor parameters. This function is not created by me. The usage of that function is as follows `this.router.navigate(['buses','big','bus-details'],queryParamas:{busId:'abc'});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update that I added to my question I was able to solve my problem although I wasn't able to figure out the root cause of why this was happening. Previously when I was facing the problem I was calling `navigate` function from the `Router` object received in a component which was declared inside Feature module and I also observed this navigation error was occuring only from feature module component and not from component defined in AppModule so there was a service which was defined in `AppModule`, I first injected that service in feature module component and then used the `Router` object of that service to call navigate function like shown below and everything was running smoothly.

```
this.globalService.router.navigate(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look more into [Navigation Extras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#skipLocationChange). The skipLocationChange will not push a new state to the history. Or the preserveQueryParams.

Although it looks more like that when you navigate to that url something is triggered from your code like the OnChanges function. Or maybe there is a redirect in the app.routing module which catches that navigation. Can not say much without any code

Comment: SkipLocation check is not changing the url at all when trying to navigate to `buses/big/bus-details?busId=abc`. It is stuck at same url from which I want to navigate from. This is not what I am looking for, I just want to prevent update of URL from `buses/big/bus-details?busId=abc` to `buses/big/bus-details` and also prevention of pushing new state to history. I checked there is nothing in code which making another navigation like you said there might be a navigation in `OnChanges` function and I am calling this navigation from feature module and there is no other route which is being catched.